# How to increase cell padding in jquery datatables?

Tags: php, jquery, css, datatables

I am using [jQuery DataTable plugin](http://datatables.net/). Is there any option to increase cell padding or cell spacing in tables.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
table.dataTable td {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. Go to http://www.datatables.net/ref and look for sClass. This option allows you to add a class to a cell. The class will style the cell however you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

Short-Answer: No http://www.datatables.net/ref